# Set fixed height in Flot js

Tags: javascript, flot

I use a [lib](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#introduction) for plotting. I want to set fixed height for plot. Now plot's height depends of data displayed inside. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is:

> You need to set the width and height of this div, otherwise the plot
>   library doesn't know how to scale the graph. You can do it inline like
>   this:
>
> `<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>`